# Why should I call self=[super init]

Tags: objective-c

Let's say I create my class and its `init` method. Why should I call and return value of superclass `init` assigned to self? Which cases it covers?

I would appreciate examples why would I need it for Cocoa superclass and non-Cocoa.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You mean why

```
self = [super init];
```

rather than

```
[super init];
```

Two reasons:

1. in initialisation, failure is indicated by returning nil.  You need to know if initialisation of the super object failed.
2. the super class might choose to replace the self returned by +alloc with a different object.  This is rare but happens most frequently with [class clusters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html).

Edited in response to Michael's comment:

> I can understand why I need to save and return [super init]. But is it just convention and good looking makes us use self as a temporary variable to pass result along?

No.  Instance variables are accessed relative to the self pointer, so in the following:

```
-(id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        myBoolIvar = YES; 
       // The above is an implicit version of self->myBoolIvar = YES;
    }
    return self;
}
```

self has clearly got to point to the right block of memory i.e. the one you are going to return.

> The other point is that if super init returns different class instance then the rest of the code after that line may not even make sense, lead to memory leaks and crashes, not even talking about the object instantiated from that class.

That could be a problem.  If I subclassed NSNumber and [super init] decided to return an NSString (which it could - there's nothing to stop it) that would clearly be a disaster.  Whatever super returns from -init must be "compatible" with the subclass in the sense of providing space for ivars and being further subclassible or it's a horrendous bug (unless, of course, the problem is documented).  So, in general, you don't need to worry about checking the class.  However, do read the documentation.  See for instance the section on subclassing NSString in NSString's docs.

Comment: Good catch with the much overlooked reason two. Nice answer!

Comment: so there are two points I would like to clarify. To bubble `init` results from top to my class and my subclasses, I can understand why I need to save and return `[super init]`. But is it just convention and good looking makes us use self as a temporary variable to pass result along? The other point is that if `super init` returns different class instance then the rest of the code after that line may not even make sense, lead to memory leaks and crashes, not even talking about the object instantiated from that class. So I may also need to check the class returned by `super init`.

Comment: thanks for update indeed. That explains and made a lot more clear for me. Will need to ask couple more questions to draw full picture in my head, will do that in separate question.

Answer (score 27):

I know it is a little bit late for my answer, but I cannot stop myself from posting a link which I found very useful in clearing my doubt about this problem.

[Matt Gallagher: What does it mean when you assign [super init] to self?](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/what-does-it-mean-when-you-assign-super.html)

**EDIT:** As per the comments, here are the essential points in the link

To understand why `self=[super init];` we need to consider many points. Let's tackle it one by one.

**What is `self`**

Every method has two hidden parameters: `self` and `_cmd`. So the method call

```
- (id)initWithString:(NSString *)aString
```

is changed by compiler into a function call like this

```
id initWithString(id self, SEL _cmd, NSString *aString);
```

**Why do we need self?**

The reality is that the compiler uses the `self` parameter to resolve any reference to an instance variable inside a method.

Suppose that we have a method `setValueToZero` and `value` is an instance variable of the class it belongs to, then the implementation

```
- (void)setValueToZero
{
    value = 0;
}
```

will be converted by the compiler into a function like this

```
void setValueToZero(id self, SEL _cmd)
{
    self->value = 0;
}
```

**Do `self` already have a value when `init` is called?**

Following is an example of a typical object creation and initialization.

```
[[MyClass alloc] initWithString:@"someString"]
```

Here, by the time we get into the `initWithString` method, self will have the newly allocated object as its value (i.e., the return value from `[MyClass alloc]`). In fact, it is almost guaranteed to be the correct, final value.

**Why `self = [super init];`?**

It is because `[super init]` is permitted to do one of the three things:

1. Return its own receiver (the `self` pointer doesn't change) with inherited instance values initialized.
2. Return a different object with inherited instance values initialized.
3. Return `nil`, indicating failure.

In the first case, assignment has no effect on `self`. In the third case, the initialization has failed, `self` is set to `nil` and it is returned.

The reason behind assignment to `self` is with the second case. Consider the following

```
- (id)initWithString:(NSString *)aString
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        instanceString = [aString retain];
    }
    return self;
}
```

We want the conversion from

```
instanceString = [aString retain];
```

to

```
self->instanceString = [aString retain];
```

to act on the correct value and thus we have to change the value of `self`.

**When would `[super init]` return a different object?**

In one of the following situations

1. Singleton object (always returns the singleton instead of any subsequent allocation)
2. Other unique objects (`[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0]` always returns the global "zero" object)
3. Class clusters substitute private subclasses when you initialize an instance of the superclass.
4. Classes which choose to reallocate the same (or compatible) class based on parameters passed into the initializer.

In all but the final case, continuing to initialize the returned object if it changes is a mistake — the returned object is already completely initialized and isn't necessary related to your class anymore. So a better init approach will be as follows

```
- (id)initWithString:(NSString *)aString
{
    id result = [super init];
    if (self == result)
    {
        instanceString = [aString retain];
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Conclusion**

You don't need to assign `[super init]` to `self` to make most classes work. In some obscure cases, it is actually the wrong thing to do.

So why do we continue to assign to `self`? It's the traditional template for an initializer, and although it's wrong in some cases, it is right in other cases which have been written to expect this approach.

Comment: As per Josh's comment, please can you include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the [link for reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot and deletion.

Comment: Great answer except for the *a better init approach*.  That is completely wrong;  it is not safe to assume that the different object will be initialized.   Look at `NSString`;  the `init` methods pretty much always return a different instance, but they *are not pre-existing instances*.   If you are looking to enforce singletons, then *that must be done prior to the call to `init` and *must* be outside initialization flow *or* your subclass initializers must be aware of the singleton pattern employed.

Answer (score 4):

Basically every Objective-C class is a subclass. It's either some class you've specified or NSObject.

In the subclass (your class that you're working on) you call
self = [super init]

What this basically does is calls the super class's (the ones I mentioned above) init method (the constructor) and assigns it to the current class.

This makes sure that the superclasses' initializing method is called.

Now for
If(self)
This basically checks if the above piece of code worked.

This is done to insure that if you call some Instance Variable of the super class, you'll be able to do so.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, setting self to [super init] does nothing since [super init] will wind up returning self anyway. There are some rare cases, however, where [super init] will return something different. It may return nil if it fails to initialize the superclass for some reason or it may decide to return a completely different object.

Answer (score 1):

### Source

---

[Implementing The Designated Initializer](http://technicaltut.blogspot.com/2016/01/ios-objective-c-implementing-designated.html)

**

### self

**
Inside a method, self is an implicit local variable. There is no need to declare it, and it is automatically set to point to the object that was sent the message. (Something like this in Android programming.) Typically, self is used that an object can send a message to itself. Example here:

```
 return self;
```

**

### super

**
When we overriding a method, we want to keep what method of the superclass is doing and have your subclass add something new on that. To make it easier, there is compiler directive in Objective-C called super.
**How does super work?** Usually when you send a message to an object, the search for a method of that name starts in the object's class. If there is no such method, the search continues in the superclass of the object. The search will continue up the inheritance hierarchy until a suitable method is found. (If it gets to the top of the hierarchy and no method is found, an exception is thrown).
When we send a message to super, we are sending message to self, but the search for the method skips the object's class and start at the superclass. In the above case, we send init message to super. This calls NSObject's init method.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to initialize the object somehow, and presumably you want to do any initialization a superclass required be done, since you're descending from it.

Comment: then why can't I just call `[super init]` without returning the result as self? self is modified locally anyway as far as I understand.

Comment: And what is self then? You are saying "I am now the object that `[super init]` returns."

Comment: so doing `return [super init]` is not valid? If I modify self it will be only in the scope of `init` method

Comment: If you `return [super init]` you might as well not bother with an init method at all - then `[super init]` will effectively be called directly.