# What does the assignment of super init to self do?

Tags: objective-c

Given this piece of code:

```
-(id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
       ...
    }
    return self;
}
```

I understand that we are checking that the super init did not fail but otherwise it makes no sense to me and I would appreciate an explanation for a noob.

Why would I want to assign the result of super init to self.  If I delete this method from my class, the super init method is going to be called anyway and there is going to be no assignment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why should I call self=\[super init\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956943/why-should-i-call-self-super-init)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In principle (and, surprisingly, even in practice) `[super init]` can return a different object! See http://mikeash.com/pyblog/the-how-and-why-of-cocoa-initializers.html and http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/what-does-it-mean-when-you-assign-super.html for more information.