# Why to use [super init] in Objective C constructors?

Tags: objective-c, constructor

Say I have a class named Item. Which is a superclass of NewsItem and TwitterItem.

If I want to create some NewsItem's do I have to use (inside constructor)

```
    self = [super init];
```

If yes, why? In Java/C# I would just do,

```
    NewsItem n = new NewsItem();
```

I don't have to do anything with superclasses in Java/C#. Just can't grasp it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why should I call self=\[super init\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956943/why-should-i-call-self-super-init)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java and C#, the compiler automatically makes your constructor call the superclass constructor if you don't explicitly call it.  For example, [the “Java Tutorials” say this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html):

> If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass constructor, the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the no-argument constructor of the superclass. If the super class does not have a no-argument constructor, you will get a compile-time error. Object does have such a constructor, so if Object is the only superclass, there is no problem.

In Objective-C, the compiler doesn't do it automatically, so you have to do it yourself.

Comment: This was exactly the explanation I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Because your superclass (and your superclass's superclass) need a chance to initialize, too.

And, keep in mind, that your superclass will [rarely] return nil or a different instance.

Which is why you do:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        ... init stuff ....
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Kevin added the return type. Thanks.  Not strictly necessary as (id) is the default, but I prefer it, too.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are overriding the init message. If you don't override it then `[[NewsItem alloc] init]` would just call the superclass' init message. In C#, you might use [base](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx) to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

since your custom object will at least inherit from the mothers of all Objects: NSObject, you have to call '[super init];'
'super' simply does call the init Method of its superclass